# com.sun.identity.idm.AMIdentity's store method is throwing java.util.MissingResourceException

Tags: java, openam

We are using OpenAM 9.5.3 version in our product. And to store a new user in OpenAM data store, AMIdentity's store method is called.

But we are frequently below exception. It so happens is that system will be running fine to days and suddenly one day this problem shows up. And restarting the services is the only workaround.

```
com.my.company.security.auth.server.AuthClass::handlePostAuthSuccess() - ::handlePostAuthSuccess() - An exception occurred during Post Authentication Processing: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key -1
                at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.identity.idm.plugins.ldapv3.LDAPv3Bundle.getString(LDAPv3Bundle.java:48)
                at com.sun.identity.idm.plugins.ldapv3.LDAPv3Repo.handleLDAPException(LDAPv3Repo.java:6027)
                at com.sun.identity.idm.plugins.ldapv3.LDAPv3Repo.setAttributes(LDAPv3Repo.java:4065)
                at com.sun.identity.idm.plugins.ldapv3.LDAPv3Repo.setAttributes(LDAPv3Repo.java:3845)
                at com.sun.identity.idm.server.IdServicesImpl.setAttributes(IdServicesImpl.java:1698)
                at com.sun.identity.idm.server.IdCachedServicesImpl.setAttributes(IdCachedServicesImpl.java:522)
                at com.sun.identity.idm.AMIdentity.store(AMIdentity.java:586)
                at com.my.company.security.auth.server.AuthClass.handlePostAuthSuccess(AuthClass.java:1810)
```

Code used to access `store` method is :

[image]

I have not been able to figure out what could be causing this exception? If any of you have faced this issue and know how to get this resolved.

**Note** that OpenAM upgrade is not an open for us.

Answer (score 1):

I think the direct cause is [OPENAM-1123](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-1123) but it may not be the root cause.

At first, you should check the debug logs at message level.